# Uploading a File in Autodesk Forge, results in "URN not in the right Format" error

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk

Im trying to upload a file using Autodesk FOrge
Im on the last step, creating version for the file
Im getting an error in my response saying : URN is not in proper format

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://developer.api.autodesk.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.api+json"));

            string apiUrl = $"/data/v1/projects/{projectId}/items";

# Create JSON payload
            string jsonPayload = $@"
            {{
                ""jsonapi"": {{ ""version"": ""1.0"" }},
                ""data"": {{
                    ""type"": ""items"",
                    ""attributes"": {{
                        ""displayName"": ""{fileName}"",
                        ""extension"": {{
                            ""type"": ""items:autodesk.core:File"",
                            ""version"": ""1.0""
                        }}
                    }},
                    ""relationships"": {{
                        ""tip"": {{
                            ""data"": {{ ""type"": ""versions"", ""id"": ""1"" }}
                        }},
                        ""parent"": {{
                            ""data"": {{ ""type"": ""folders"", ""id"": ""{folderId}"" }}
                        }}
                    }}
                }},
                ""included"": [
                    {{
                        ""type"": ""versions"",
                        ""id"": ""1"",
                        ""attributes"": {{
                            ""name"": ""{fileName}"",
                            ""extension"": {{
                                ""type"": ""versions:autodesk.core:File"",
                                ""version"": ""1.0""
                            }}
                        }},
                        ""relationships"": {{
                            ""storage"": {{
                                ""data"": {{ ""type"": ""objects"", ""id"": ""{objectId}"" }}
                            }}
                        }}
                    }}
                ]
            }}";

            // Convert JSON payload to StringContent
            var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.api+json");

            // Send POST request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Response Content:\n{responseContent}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create project item. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
```

where in my objectId and folderId starts with urn:adsk ....

I was expecting - > File Successfully uploaded

Comment: For uploading files to BIM360 or ACC, the item extension should be `items:autodesk.bim360:File`, not `items:autodesk.core:File`. and the version extension should be `versions:autodesk.bim360:File`, not `versions:autodesk.core:File`.